# How to make a proof your own?

Tags: proof-writing, self-learning

Often, in the interest of time, We look at proofs done by others. It could be on stack, in a textbook, or shown by a friend. In all cases, you don't get the same amount of mental compression of the proof as you do when you do it yourself.

It's one thing to be able to reproduce the proof after careful study of the logic, but there's always a nagging feeling that it was an idea that was inplanted in your head. (Reference to Inception)

Is this just part of the inevitable process of learning from others or is there a way to make a proof your own? Any thoughts?

Comment: Practice practice practice.

Comment: I think a good way is to ask your own question. Do not try to prove questions someone else have already asked. Often you find out that the thing you asked yourself is either trivial or somebody else had thought of it already, but every once in a while, you can manage to find an interesting hard question without much of scienitific significance, but then your creativity can start to fully take place. My most interesting question was about ternary operators and remains unanswered even with the assistance of stackexchange. If I ever manage to answer that, it will be I guess a proof of my own.

Comment: "we look at proofs" Who's "we"? Is Yashmnash a group, or is this meant to be a majestic plural (then, you should spell it "We look at...", I guess).

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: If you can't reproduce a reasonably short proof on demand, you haven't really understood it. Work on really understanding it, and that means exploring why that particular idea works, why some others might not etc.

Comment: One small thing you can do to make a proof your own is to add some detailed explanation of steps that were less explained in the source that you read. This is certainly far less than completely making up your own proof but it is an example of a small step that you could take in that direction.